# How to solve time interval runniung fastly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my below code the words are randomly pushed to the div.The word should change after every 5 secs. Its working in normal condition. If i click "New" and "Seen" the word changing immediately after every 3 seconds.But i given 5 secs to change.I don't why its changing within seconds.Please review my below code.

```js
wordlist = []
wordlist.push({
  word: "ABUNDANCES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "BOTANOMANCY",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "CALUMNIATED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "DECISIONING",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "ENCAPSULATE",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "FINGERNAILS",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "GALLIVANTED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "HEADBANGING",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "IMPASSIONED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "JEWELFISHES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "KILOGRAMMES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "LAMPLIGHTER",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "MANICURISTS",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "NEPHROTOXIC",
  seen: false
})

function loadRandom() {
  n = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length);
  $("#status").text(wordlist[n].word);
}
$(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(loadRandom, 5000);
});
loadRandom(); // for initial display


function seen() {
  loadRandom();
}

function unseen() {
  loadRandom();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status" class="keyword">Test</div>
<a class="btn waves-effect red" id="seen" onClick="seen()">Seen</a>
<a class="btn waves-effect red" id="unseen" onClick="unseen()">New</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you want? you set interval 5sec but you want interval run fastly. if so you could put interval smaller than 5000 (5second)

Comment: In normal its changing the word within 5 secs. If i click the "New" and "Seen" button its changing within 3 secs. But i given interval as 5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on 'seen' or 'new' word is changed as expected but keep in mind setInterval is still active and it will change the word after 5 seconds irrespective of user clicking 'seen' or 'new' buttons.

So if you clicked on 'new' after say 'n' seconds, next new word will be rendered after (5-n) seconds and not necessarily after 3 seconds as you described. All you need to do is clear interval when calling 'loadRandom' through 'seen' or 'unseen' methods.

Refactor your code as below:

```js
wordlist = [];

wordlist.push({
  word: "ABUNDANCES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "BOTANOMANCY",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "CALUMNIATED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "DECISIONING",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "ENCAPSULATE",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "FINGERNAILS",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "GALLIVANTED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "HEADBANGING",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "IMPASSIONED",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "JEWELFISHES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "KILOGRAMMES",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "LAMPLIGHTER",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "MANICURISTS",
  seen: false
})
wordlist.push({
  word: "NEPHROTOXIC",
  seen: false
})

var interval;

function loadRandom() {
     n = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length);
     $("#status").text(wordlist[n].word);
}

function setMyInterval(){
    interval= setInterval(loadRandom, 5000); 
}

$(function() {
    setMyInterval();
});

loadRandom(); // for initial display

function seen() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    loadRandom();
    setMyInterval();
};
function unseen() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    loadRandom();
    setMyInterval();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status" class="keyword">Test</div>
<a class="btn waves-effect red" id="seen" onClick="seen()">Seen</a>
<a class="btn waves-effect red" id="unseen" onClick="unseen()">New</a>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I need to add progress bar with this for every 5 second it needs to initalize  'var value = 0;
 function barAnim(){
  value += 5;
  $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value );    
  if ( value == 25 || value == 55 || value == 85 ) { 
   return setTimeout(barAnim, 150); 
  }
  return value >= 100 || setTimeout(barAnim, 150);
 }
 
 setTimeout(barAnim, 150);'